# OneToMany: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

Having these classes:

*Vehicle.java*:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    private final int vehicleId;
    
    private final String vehicleName;
}
```

*User.java*:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "UserDetails")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    
    private String userName;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId")
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

*DemoApp.java*:

```java
@Bean
CommandLineRunner dataLoader3(VehicleRepository vehicleRepo, UserRepository userRepo){
  return new CommandLineRunner() {
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      Vehicle v = new Vehicle(0, "Car");
      vehicleRepo.save(v);
      Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle(1, "Bus");
      vehicleRepo.save(v2);

      User u = new User();
      u.setUserName("First User");
      u.setVehicles(Arrays.asList(v, v2));

      userRepo.save(u);
    }
  }
}
```

The spring gives 2 errors regarding foreign key:

> Error executing DDL "alter table vehicle drop foreign key
> FKk65fmqecth7bpxy163dwj685f" via JDBC Statement

and then

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`test_db`.`vehicle`, CONSTRAINT `FKk65fmqecth7bpxy163dwj685f` FOREIGN
> KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `user_details` (`user_id`))

I have just tried to change the `@JoinColumn` name on `@OneToMany` relation. How to solve this?

PS: I have deleted all created tables before so there are no constraints left.

PPS: using MySQL.

Comment: "alter table vehicle drop foreign key FKk65fmqecth7bpxy163dwj685f" - why is this occurring if you deleted all the tables? Something is calling DDL to try to drop a constraint and the error might give a clue to the problem you are hitting, especially since it says it cannot drop it and that same constraint gets in the way of some other update statement. Since it is mentioning 'VEHICLE_ID' and you are using "vehicleId", I suspect you are using DDL generation and letting it try to 'fix' an existing schema, but it cannot. Drop it entirely, ensure they are gone, fix your entities, and start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId") definition on the User entity:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId")
private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
```

This tells JPA to create and use a 'vehicleId' column within the Vehicle table to use to reference the User entity. Your Vehicle entity/table though already defines a 'vehicleId', which causes errors and conflicts - especially as one User is referencing two vehicles which is likely going to try to have them use the same value for the vehicleId.

Try:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead, which will create a 'userId' column within vehicle to identify the one (and only one) user that can be associated to the vehicle in this type of mapping. This is commonly done using

```
public class User {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    
    private String userName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    private final int vehicleId;
    private final String vehicleName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User user;
}
```

Alternatively as was suggested, you can just leave off the joinColumn. This will create a join table for this relationship which will look much like a ManyToMany relationship, but with restrictions on the relation table.

Comment: That works (having `@JoinColumn(name="userId")`, but if I run that, the jpa will create only one vehicle (`v2`, "Bus") is inserted. The `v1` ("Car") is not. Does this have something to do with it?

Comment: It shouldn't - what happens on the second vehicle save call? Turn on SQL logging to see what JPA/Spring is doing during that call.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, you should not use `@JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId")` in `User` class. Please try the following (I assume that `Vehicle`s not referenced in any `User` are not needed):

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "UserDetails")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    
    private String userName;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Is the unidirectional relationship intended?

Comment: Why shouldn't the JoinColumn be used? Both the original form with JoinColumn and this one without it make this a unidirectional OneToMany mapping - the only difference is that yours requires an extra join table while the OP's was using a foreign key in the target (Vehicle) table similar to how a bidirectional 1:m would.

Comment: I should have been more detailed in the sentence `you should not use @JoinColumn`, you are right. I meant `you should not use @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId")` for the reasons you depicted thoroughly. Regarding the unidirectional relationship, I was aware that my suggestion also creates one, I was just wondering if this was in fact intended.